# Is there any programmatical advantage of using != vs <> or vice versa for not equal?

Tags: operators

While studying about various operators, this thing came up to my mind..!

Is there any programmatical advantage of using != vs <> or vice versa for not equal?

Asking this out of curiosity, it would be great if any of you guys can shed some light on this !

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: when I said programmatical advantage, I meant the advantage in performance

Comment: It all compiles down to the same thing. Doesn't matter.

Comment: FORTRAN uses `.NE.`. It is simply up to the language designer what to use. They are only symbols.

Comment: Is this seriously a question about whether Pascal's <> is better than C++'s !=?  This is not a substantive question.

Comment: You might (not) want to compare JavaScript's `!=` and `!==`.

Answer (score 0):

No there is no difference between them. When the are both available, they are equivalent. For compiled languages they end up as the same instructions, there isn't two different comparison instructions for them.

Both are sufficiently clear, and there is no apparent risk of confusion with other operators.

A possible candidate for `!=` would be to confuse it with `=!`, i.e. an assignment operator and a not operator. Possible candidates for `<>` might be to confuse it with shift operators `<<` and `>>`. Neither is very likely.